# How to get the precise position of an error within the line in Python

Tags: python, exception, runtime-error, error-messaging

How to get the precise position of an error within the line in Python? The Python interpreter gives the line of the error and the type of the Error, but if there are more points in the line that could cause that error then there is ambiguity, here is a toy example:

`example.py`

```
xs = []
ys = {"item": xs}
zs=  {"item":ys}
print(zs['item']['item']['item'])
```

Where the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(zs['item']['item']['item'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here, considering that `xs`, `ys` and `zs` could be the result of long computation, it could not be clear which one of the `['item']` triggered the `TypeError`.

I would prefer an error message like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(zs['item']['item']['item'])
                            ^-------
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

That tells me that the problem is in the last accessing with `['item']`.

I am using Python 3.8.16

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been added in Python 3.11.1, in this new version the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/p.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(zs['item']['item']['item'])
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Telling you that the error is caused by the third `['item']`.

You can install it on a Linux system with:

```
apt install python3.11
```

And run a python file with the new Python version with:

```
python3.11 example.py
```